# How to route web traffic to multiple virtual web servers on a single IP address

Tags: virtualization, routing, vmware-esxi

I have a single ESXi 5 server which is connected to a single IP address.  Within this server I have created 2 VMs:

1. Windows 2008 IIS Web Server (`a.site.com`)
2. CentOS Apache Web Server (`b.site.com`)

I am unsure of how to route traffic to the correct VM based on the host header?

Comment: they listen on different ports, I think

Comment: What device or software is going to do the routing?

Comment: @David can the ESXi server itself do the routing?  I've got no idea to be honest.

Comment: I don't know of any web routing software that runs on ESXi itself. Something is going to have to receive the connection, look at the 'Host' header, and then either redirect or proxy the returned page.

Comment: Vote to move to Serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a reverse proxy on the host machine (or on one of the VMs to which you'll route all requests), which will internally forward requests to individual VMs based on the host header. Both VMs must be accessible from the host machine on a specific IP address or port.

As for the reverse proxy - one option is Apache with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) is a lightweight alternative. According to this post, [nginx](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176958#774596) can be configured as a reverse proxy which works based on Host value as well.

(Disclaimer: I didn't do this practically myself.)

Comment: Async servers like Nginx and Varnish that were largely designed to reverse-proxy are great fits here, but the lightest-weight (not necessarily fastest) option would definitely be to piggyback on the existing Apache instance and proxy some subdomains to the IIS host.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with IBM HTTP Server (IHS) which I don't believe is free, but my favorite GPL version of a reverse proxy is Pound ([www.apsis.ch/pound/](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)).  Check out the section "Virtual Hosts (In General)" on that page.  I believe this is what you are looking for.  Below is a slightly tweaked version of the config from that page...

```
 ListenHTTP
            Address 1.2.3.4
            Port    80

            Service
                HeadRequire "Host: .*a.site.com*"

                BackEnd
                    Address 192.168.0.10
                    Port    80
                End
            End

            Service
                HeadRequire "Host: .*b.site.com.*"

                BackEnd
                    Address 192.168.0.10
                    Port    80
                End
            End
        End
```